# Passing Authentication Token with Breeze query

Tags: breeze

My server side breeze api calls require me to validate the token value provided with each call before returning any data. To achieve this, i am passing TokenId with each Entity Query using withParameters function of breeze Entity Query and specify the parameter on my server side controller action as illustrated below.

Following is how i am doing it right now:

**Client Side**

```
function GetCustomers(){
    return breeze.EntityQuery.from('Customers')
    .withParameters({ TokenId: 'token value' })
    .using(entityManager).execute() 
}
```

**Server Side**

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Customer> Customers(string TokenId)
{
     //server side logic
}
```

This for some reason looks to me can be simplified using some configuration on Breeze Entity Manager which automatically adds the parameter value to every query sent from client. And also, on server side, i don't think its necessary to have tokenId parameter defined on each controller method. This should be easy to solve with Action Filters on the server side.

Can someone point me in right direction if it is possible and how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you always passing it as a parameter or can you pass it as a header?  If you can pass it as a custom header you can search for 'define custom headers breeze.js' to see how that can be done

Comment: @PWKad: I suppose i can pass this information in header. I tried this option and worked. Thanks

How do i flag your comment as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always pass custom authentication information, such as tokens, in the headers.

If you can pass it as a custom header you can search for 'define custom headers breeze.js' to see how that can be done.

A good example - 
http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/server-ajaxadapter.html

Also keep in mind that if you put the token in the query string that is persisted by most of the servers that your call is crossing over, making it much easier to find tokens for your application if an evil-doer were to download the logs from that server.

Also keep in mind that if you are using cross-domain requests (CORS) you will need to enable the custom header on the server side that is receiving the call.

Answer (score 0):

To give an example of the answer above:

```
    // get the current default Breeze AJAX adapter
    var ajaxAdapter: any = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance('ajax');

    // set fixed headers
    ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings = {
        headers: {
            "Bearer": this.bearerToken
        }
    };
```

Note also that if you are using ASP.net Identity (which includes a cookie based authentication), you must include this code so that the asp.net pipeline does NOT use that cookie:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.Filters.Add(new Ask.Filters.RequireHttpsAttribute());

        //This forces http header authentication which is required for web api calls.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Note also that you should use only https, with this filter:

```
public class RequireHttpsAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public int Port { get; set; }

    public RequireHttpsAttribute()
    {
        Port = 443;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var request = actionContext.Request;

        if (request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

            if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Get || request.Method == HttpMethod.Head)
            {
                var uri = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);
                uri.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
                uri.Port = this.Port;

                response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Found;
                response.Headers.Location = uri.Uri;
            }
            else
            {
                response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
            }

            actionContext.Response = response;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, make sure you use the `[Authorize]` and `[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]` attribute on your controllers.

See the [Full Sample and article on asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using oAuth tokens in the header.  I am currently using Auth0, but there are many others including Google Firebase.  BreezeJS has been expanded such that it will accept AuthHttp as it's HTTP client for all calls.  AuthHttp will automatically add a bearer token to the header of every call to the server.

One the server side it's a matter of adding the proper oAuth client lib (via Nuget) which automatically parses out the bearer token, validates it against the oAuth server, and makes claims available for use within your API call.

For example, in my implementation my api code will receive a claim that contains the users id, which I can then validate against my db and use to filter all actions.  This keeps user B from loading user A's data by directly calling the api in a browser.

For example, all API calls are first validated by the oAuth subsystem.  Once my api code is executed I know the caller has been validated and I use the passed claims (user id) to access only the calling users data - REGARDLESS what was actually requested by the API call parameters (which can be forged as easily as editing a URL string).

A simple example of this would be exposing your UserSet in the API.  If you don't filter by the user claim id you must realize that every user in your system will be accessible by constructing a simple URL in a browser.

Here I filter out and return only the user record identified by the user id in the auth claim.  Note I use #if AUTH simply for testing as PROD will always have AUTH turned on.

```
#if AUTH
    [Authorize]
#endif
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableBreezeQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 5)]
    public IQueryable<User> UserSet()
    {

#if AUTH
        Guid guid = userGuid();
        return _efContext.Context.UserSet.Where(x => x.active && x.guid == guid);

#else
        return _efContext.Context.UserSet;
#endif
    }
```

All of this sounds complicated, but it really is quite easy to implement.

Thanks,
Mike